# ShowDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner not showing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center, achievements

In Unity-iPhone, I'm using GameCenterPlatform.ShowDefaultAchievementCompletionBanner(true) to activate gamecenter completion banner. There's no problem if the achievement was completed from 0% to 100%, the banner is shown. However if the achievement progress is updated gradually(e.g. 25% for each submission), by the time the achievement is completed, it doesn't show the completion banner.

How can I make it show the banner by the time the achievement reaches 100% despite it being cumulative? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!